# .NET Framework method to quickly build directories

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there a quick way to join paths like the Join-Path function in Powershell?  For example, I have two parts of a path "C:\foo" and a subdirectory "bar".  Join-Path will join these and take care of the backslash delimiters.  Is there a built-in method for this in .NET, or do I need to handle this myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your friend:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.Path.Combine is the one you're looking for. There's quite a few useful methods on the Path class.

Answer (score 1):

*Path.Combine* is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[System.IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)